# XCode cannot find my GoogleService-Info.plist file when building a Kotlin Multiplatform Project

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, crashlytics, kotlin-multiplatform

I am having issues getting XCode to detect my Google Services files.  I already have firebase/crashlytics setup and working in the Android part of my KMM app, and have created the according expect/actual wrapper to handle calls to the firebase library. My issue is that when building the app via XCode, I am shown the following error:
`error: Could not get GOOGLE_APP_ID in Google Services file from build environment`

I have downloaded the GoogleService-Info.plist file from firebase as directed to and added the required AppDelegate calling firebase.configure(), added dependencies via swifts package manager, etc. I added the GoogleService-Info.plist file to my project via 'Add Files to "iosApp"'ensuring to select the target (of which I have just one).
Placing the file in either the root directory "iosApp", or the module directory "iosApp/iosApp" results in the same error being thrown.

[image: File Structure]

[image: Target Membership]

[image: Error]

Any suggestions are appreciated. I come from an Android development background. So I'm uncertain whether this is an oversight I have made in the iOS firebase setup, or whether this is a greater incompatibility issue coming from Kotlin Multiplatform being used for this project.